# Does Linux kernel uses fonts from /usr/share/consolefonts? Is it safe for working kernel?

Tags: kernel, tty, console, fonts

**OS:** Ubuntu 18.04. I think it is distribution-independent. The Arch Linux uses the same principle, but do it by another way.

I set the `tty`'s font by editing the `/etc/default/console-setup` file:

```
CODESET="guess"
FONTFACE="TerminusBold"
FONTSIZE="22x11"
```

The font's file is located in the `/usr/share/consolefonts/`. It has `psf` format.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC_Screen_Font):

> PC Screen Font (PSF) is a bitmap font format currently employed by the
>   Linux kernel for console fonts. Documentation of the PSF file format
>   can be found within the source code of the Linux Kernel.

**Questions:**

1. Does kernel load this file into the kernel space?
2. If not, then how the `tty` (which resides in the kernel) renders characters from the `.psf` file, which resides in the `/usr/share/consolefonts/`?
3. I were thinking, that the kernel is a solid piece of code, which doesn't use any user files (except kernel modules), for reliability and security reasons. Am I wrong? Or console fonts are exception?
4. How can I check, which `.psf` file was loaded specifically? Because the `/usr/share/consolefonts/` folder has many `TerminusBold22x11.psf.gz` files, with different codesets. I want to know which particular file was used. I check `dmesg` and `syslog`, but didn't find such information there.

Comment: The place to look is [`console_ioctl`](https://linux.die.net/man/4/console_ioctl).

Comment: @ThomasDickey Did you mean, use `console_ioctl` for checking, which .psf file was loaded specifically? Does this method require writing a `C` program?

Comment: If you *read* the whole manual page, it answers your questions by pointing out some misconceptions.

Comment: fonts are loaded into user memory somehow and then copied (might be an different-from-userspace internal format) into kernel. No file have to be involved. This answers 124, then 3, kernel can load module from fd or memory, providing more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer to the **4-th** question for Ubuntu 18.04:

```
sudo strace -s99 setupcon 2>&1 | grep '.psf'
```

**Output**

```
read(3, "/etc/console-setup/cached_Uni2-TerminusBold22x11.psf.gz\n", 128)
```

**Explanation:**

By using the `setupcon` program the `systemd` does console setup on the OS booting. It can be viewed in this file: `/lib/systemd/system/console-setup.service`. So, by repeating `setupcon` manually, we have possibility to `strace` its system calls and find the used font file.

> **setupcon**  is a program for fast and easy setup of the font and the
>   keyboard on the console.  Most of the time  you  invoke  setupcon  without
>          arguments.   The  keyboard configuration is specified in ~/.keyboard or
>          /etc/default/keyboard.  The font configuration is specified in  **~/.console-setup** or **/etc/default/console-setup**.

Comment: The other three parts, as noted, can be answered by reading the manual page and realizing that the kernel provides the *way* for an *application* to load the font, but doesn't reach out and read the files itself.